# Can I run Elastic server on manage server for in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, hosting, web-hosting

I have Elastic search-rails application up and running 
Actually  its on a root server.

Is it possible to move it to a manage server?

What is necessary  requirement for it?

can any one suggest me answer in detail ,i am new at rails-es hosting

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bonsai](http://www.bonsai.io/) which is also [available](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bonsai) in heroku.

Comment: Yes it is a managed server, all you need to do is integrate bonsai client in your application and create your Elasticsearch indexes. If you are deploying on heroku, Bonsai has an add-on that you can install for your app. More details are on the links i provided in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Facetflow](https://facetflow.com/) which is a managed and hosted Elasticsearch solution. Your rails app would run on a different server, like for example a [Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/ruby/) website (which is managed).